# How to replace selenium framework property file value from bamboo variable?

Tags: selenium, ant, frameworks, bamboo, properties-file

I am working with a selenium framework that contains a property file and by changing values of different key values like URL and port and all in it, gives me the flexibility to test but when it came to integrating with bamboo, I wanted to do it using bamboo variable but no luck so far. I am using ANT and testNG in my framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass value to ant as:

```
-DpropertyName=itsValue
```

For example for below project,

```
<project>
    <target name="selenium">
        <property name="url" value="."/>
        <echo message="URL value is ${url}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

you can pass URL as

```
ant -Durl="https://www.google.com" selenium
```

This prints

```
 [echo] URL value is https://www.google.com
```